# React Native ios picker is always open

Tags: ios, react-native, picker

I have two pickers on my screen. Whenever I navigate to the screen in iOS app I find that the pickers are always open and all options are visible.

[image]

It works perfectly fine in Android where the options are visible only after we click on the picker.

Can somebody suggest a solution to fix this in iOS?

Comment: How can I remove the picker line

Comment: You can, only for iOS, show the selected value as touchable text which when touched make the picker visible. Then hide the picker again after choose an item.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use ActionSheet instead of Picker on iOS.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/actionsheetios

As answered by jevakallio this is the default behaviour on iOS. But this doesn't give a good UX so remove all picker components and replace with ActionSheet.

I did and it works great. The reason I preferred ActionSheet over other components suggested by jevakallio because it is developed by the RN team and has a good native feeling. The last option suggested [react-native-modal-picker](https://github.com/d-a-n/react-native-modal-picker) is also very good.

[image]

Comment: ActionSheet shouldn't be reserved for actions?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/peacechen/react-native-modal-selector also. It won't give a native picker but would give a consistent feeling on both the platform.

Comment: Okay, but what about a Picker with dozens of options (like language selection)? This is not a safe drop in replacement. This is a completely different component.

Answer (score 13):

That's just how the iOS `UIPickerView` component works - there's no way to customize it.

If you want a different kind of UI element, you'll need to write your own, or use one of the many open source libraries, such as:

- [react-native-dropdown](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-dropdown)
- [react-native-modal-dropdown](https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown)
- [react-native-modal-picker](https://github.com/d-a-n/react-native-modal-picker)

Googling with these, and similar keywords, yields many other libraries as well.

Comment: Useful. but using action sheet for a long list of data cannot be preferred. And in react-native-modal-picker/ react-native-modal-selector there remains an extra padding at the bottom. Could nt find a perfect solution for this yet.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know why you'd choose the answer with ActionSheet as accepted answer.
However I'll give a workaround for this problem:

Put this values in your state:

```
this.state= {
    pickerOpacity: 0,
    opacityOfOtherItems: 1 //THIS IS THE OPACITY OF ALL OTHER ITEMS, WHICH COLLIDES WITH YOUR PICKER.
    label: 'Firstvalue'
}
```

In your render method do following:

```
{this.checkIfIOS()}
      <Picker
         selectedValue={this.state.selected}
         style={{ height: 50, alignSelf: 'center', opacity: this.state.pickerOpacity, marginBottom:30, width: 250}}
         onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>{
            this.setState({
                selected: itemValue,
                label: itemValue
            });
            toggle();
            }
          }>
          <Picker.Item label="Your Label" value="yourValue"/>
      </Picker>
```

So now we've to check, whether our client is android or ios. Therefore import Platform and put the checkIfIos()-Method in your code:

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native'

checkIfIOS(){
        if(Platform.OS === 'ios'){ // check if ios
            console.log("IOS!!!");
            //this button will (onpress) set our picker visible
            return (<Button buttonStyle={{backgroundColor:'#D1D1D1', opacity: this.state.opacityOfOtherItems}} onPress={this.toggle()} color="#101010" title={this.state.label} onPress={this.changeOpacity}/>); 
        }else if(Platform.OS === 'android'){ //check if android
            this.setState({
                pickerOpacity: 1 //set picker opacity:1 -> picker is visible.
            });
            console.log("ANDROID!!!");
        }
    }

toggle(){
    if(Platform.OS === 'ios'){

        if(this.state.pickerOpacity == 0){
            this.setState({
                pickerOpacity: 1,
                opacityOfOtherItems: 0 // THIS WILL HIDE YOUR BUTTON!
            });
         }else{
             this.setState({
                 pickerOpacity: 0,
                 opacityOfOtherItems: 1
             });
          }
     }
}
```

**EDIT:** Screenshot with iOS ([Click here for Video](https://streamable.com/pzaio))

[image: Screenshot of DatePicker with iOS]

Comment: do you maybe have an expo snack of this? I'm having a hard time implementing this and I'm not even sure if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately not. You just have to put the toggle() & checkIfIOS() methods and run the checkIfOs before the rendering your picker and use the toggle() method in your pickers onValueChange event. If you could provide your view, can help you how to implement it.

Comment: @SercanSametSavran can you please provide a screen shots of the picker?
How does the button looks like in the view?
It appears that the implementation of this.changeOpacity() is missing

Comment: Can you provide us please with a screenshot on IOS ?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. But I did something better and uploaded a video, where you can see the datepicker in action (ios). There you go: https://streamable.com/pzaio

Comment: Share your code please. How do you actívate the picker?

Comment: @Borjante My code is already there, you have to use the toggle()-method to activate/deactivate the picker.

Comment: This is by far the best solution and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

React-native-modal-picker was discontinued.
[react-native-modal-selector](https://github.com/peacechen/react-native-modal-selector)

Answer (score 7):

use

`<Picker  itemStyle={{height:50}} > </Picker>`

it only affect ios picker. change picker itemstyle height to your standard.

Comment: Actually that was the trick for me so I don't need to use alternatives ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Extending the `ActionSheetIOS` answer, I created a custom component that is a drop-in replacement for `Picker` (I'm using `Button` from https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/overview.html):

```
import React from 'react';
import { ActionSheetIOS, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';

class PickerDropDown extends React.Component {
  onIOSButton = () => {
    let options = this.props.children.map((item, i) => {
      return item.props.label;
    });
    options.push("Cancel");
    ActionSheetIOS.showActionSheetWithOptions(
      {
        options: options,
        cancelButtonIndex: options.length - 1,
      },
      this.onIOSButtonPick
    );
  }

  onIOSButtonPick = (buttonIndex) => {
    if (buttonIndex < this.props.children.length && buttonIndex != this.props.selectedValue) {
      if (typeof this.props.selectedValue === 'undefined' || (typeof this.props.selectedValue !== 'undefined' && buttonIndex != this.findIndexForValue(this.props.selectedValue))) {
        this.props.onValueChange(this.props.children[buttonIndex].props.value, buttonIndex);
      }
    }
  }

  findLabelForValue = (searchValue) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.children.length; i++) {
      if (this.props.children[i].props.value == searchValue) {
        return this.props.children[i].props.label;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  findIndexForValue = (searchValue) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.children.length; i++) {
      if (this.props.children[i].props.value == searchValue) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }

  render() {
    if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
      let title = "";
      if (this.props.children && this.props.children.length > 0) {
        if (typeof this.props.selectedValue !== 'undefined') {
          title = this.findLabelForValue(this.props.selectedValue);
        } else {
          title = this.props.children[0].props.label;
        }
      }
      return (
      <View>
        <Button
          title={title}
          onPress={this.onIOSButton}
          type="clear"
          icon={{
            name: "arrow-drop-down",
            size: 15,
            color: "black"
          }}
          iconRight={true}
        />
     </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Picker {...this.props} />
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does it look like? a video or snapshot please

Comment: I used this and worked. Just that it is not using full available width like Picker

Comment: I wrapped it in a `<View>` and set the style prop on it. Styles on `react-native-elements` button were not applying.

Comment: Best answer. This solution uses native picker as much possible with little code. And the dropin replacement is quick to implement.

Comment: I used this class to great effect, with some small changes for styling, wrapped it in a `<View>` as suggested by @IsmailS, and published it to a Gist:  https://gist.github.com/thargenediad/7615e281baab25733ca0e7f5c7cb97d6

I hope it helps someone save time trying to style Kevin's component.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

react-native-dropdown has reference bugs
If you don't want to use Action Sheets but a 'real' picker, this one I found is way better...

https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select

Answer (score -3):

import from `native-base` library instead of `react-native`

Comment: The problem is with react native picker element, and third party libraries like `native-base` is not we are looking for