# PickerIOS is alway showing in React-Native

Tags: ios, react-native

Anyone have already use PickerIOS component ?

On Android, it's all good : when i press, my Picker is showing. But on IOS, my component is alway showing and not centered in the device.

No more information on the documentation :/

My code :

```
<PickerIOS
  selectedValue={selectedValue}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => onValueChange(itemValue)}
  style={InputStyles.picker}
>
  {items.map((item, index) =>
    <PickerIOS.Item
      key={index}
      label={item.label}
      value={item.value}
    />
  )}
</PickerIOS>
```

Screenshot :

[image]

Anyone have idea ?

Comment: Can you not use the Picker component? That works for both. It would be weird to have an iOS picker on Android.

Comment: Yep, normaly i use Picker, but on IOS, Picker is alway showing too :(

Comment: Can you share a screenshot? that is really weird

Comment: Yes, i've add on first post

Comment: I posted an answer there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native ios picker is always open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181683/react-native-ios-picker-is-always-open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good answer here:

[React Native ios picker is always open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181683/react-native-ios-picker-is-always-open)

It seems there is no way to customize the picker on iOS. Thats just the way it appears.

But they give some good pointers in that link.
Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you ShaneG :)

Comment: @StéphaneRICHIN No Problem. If it answers your question please mark it as the correct answer for this questions! :)