# How can I change a scroll wheel Picker menu to a drop down menu in React Native with Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to create a drop down menu using Expo and React-native-picker.

```js
                 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.pickerContainer}>
                    <Picker 
                        selectedValue={selectedProduct}
                        style={styles.pickerStyle}
                        itemStyle={styles.pickerItemStyle}
                        onValueChange={(value, key) => {
                            setSelectedProduct(value)
                        }}
                        
                        
                    >   
                        {getProductOptions(products)}
                    </Picker>
                </TouchableOpacity>
```

When I run `expo start` the drop down menu appears just as I want. However, when I open it in iOS simulator, I get a scroll wheel. Is there a some prop that needs to be changed to get the drop down menu in iOS?

Comment: As far as I know that is just how the ios picker looks. I think it's easier to look for alternative ui elements to choose from that look more like the drop down menu you're looking for. Relevant post https://stackoverflow.com/q/41181683/9098350.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-native-picker has a prop mode('dialog', 'dropdown') **but unfortunally it is only supported in ANDROID** . if you want to show dropdown in ios also, you have to change the library.

You can try https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker

Comment: Thanks, Dropdown-picker got me what I was looking for.